# I want to exchange value of 2 fields in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to exchange value of 2 fields in crystal report
(if Columnd5 is null want to get the value of Columnd6 to  Columnd5

I use this formula

```
if isnull ({DataTable1.Columnd5})  then
tonumber ({DataTable1.Columnd6})

else if isnull({DataTable1.Columnd6}) then
0.00
else
tonumber ({DataTable1.Columnd6})
```

but this one isn't working

Comment: What values are you getting in columnd5 and columnd6? what output do you expect?

Comment: "isn't working" is pretty vague - what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that a truth table of your formula result as follows:

```
    | Column5 value | Column6 value | result |
    | 5*            | 6*            | 6      |
    | 5*            | null          | 0      |
    | null          | 6*            | 6      |
    | null          | null          | error  |
    *means a supposed value as an example, could be any numeric value
```

But i understand your desired result would be:

```
    | Column5 value | Column6 value | result |
    | 5*            | 6*            | 5      |
    | 5*            | null          | 5      |
    | null          | 6*            | 6      |
    | null          | null          | 0      |
    *means a supposed value as an example, could be any numeric value
```

Did i really understand the problem? If so, i would suggest the following formula:

```
if not isnull ({DataTable1.Columnd5})  then
    {DataTable1.Columnd5}
else if not isnull({DataTable1.Columnd6}) then
    {DataTable1.Columnd6}
else
    0
```

Check if it would be necessary to call the ToNumber function as you need. I don't believe so. It depends on your schema.